# grep on one file and sort matches to several output files

Tags: bash, loops, awk, grep

my question concerns the following:
I have the file:

```
    FileA:
Peter Programmer
Frank Chemist
Charles Physicist
John Programmer
Alex Programmer
Harold Chemist
George Chemist
```

I now got all the job information from FileA and saved it to a unique list (FileB).

```
  FileB:
Programmer
Chemist
Physcist
```

(Assume the FileA goes on and on with many more people and redundant information)

What I want to do now is get all the job classes from FileA and create a new file for each Job-Class so that in the end I have:

```
FileProgrammer
Peter Programmer
John  Programmer
Alex  Programmer

FileChemist
Frank Chemist
Harold Chemist
George Chemist

FilePhysicist
Charles Physicist
```

I want to `grep` the pattern of the job name from the list in the Jobs File and create a new file for every job name which exists in the other original file.

So in reality, I have 56 Unique Elements in my list and the original file has several columns ( tab delimited).

What I did so far was this:

```
cut -f2 | sort | uniq > Jobs
grep -f(tr '\t' '\n' < "${Jobs}") "${FileA}" > FileA+"${Jobs}"
```

I assumed that on each new pattern match a new file would be created but I realized that it would just copy the file because there is no increment or iterative file creation.

Since my experience with bash is yet to be developed in depth, I hope you guys can help me. Thanks in advance.

@update:
Input file looks like this:

```
4   23454   22110   Direct  +   3245    Corrected
3   21254   12110   Indirect    +   2319    Paused-@2
11  45233   54103   Direct  -   1134    Not-Corrected
```

Essentially, I want everything that has the status in column 7 of Corrected to be in a file named corrected and so for every unique value of column 7.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with `grep`? Can you use `awk`?

Comment: Sure, I can use awk - I am just not that familiar with the functionality of awk in loop contexts. I tried some awk loops but somewhat failed.

Comment: Try my answer below with `Awk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `grep` inside a loop with:

```
for i in $(cat FileB); do grep $i$ FileA >> File$i; done
```

Note that in FileA of your question you wrote "Physicist" and in FileB you wrote "Physcist", so they won't match. Anyway if you write both of them properly, the above command will work.

Comment: Thanks, the line worked very well. Sorry for the typo. The only thing is that _grep_ seems to be very rough when matching the pattern. For example if the job would be Chemist-Biochemist, _grep_ would put it in the file with the other Chemists and not create another Chemist-Biochemist file. Any further advice on how to correct that? I saw that _Awk_ was proposed but I have a hard time understanding the _Awk_ code unfortunately.

Comment: @chrys: What part of it, you don't understand? Tried to explain every bit in there.

Comment: @chrys I have edited the command to force the end of the string to be grepped in order to avoid that. Check if it works now.

Answer (score 2):

The answer craves for need of *Awk*, here is how you do it,

```
awk '{unique[$2]=(unique[$2] FS $1)}\
END  {for (i in unique) { \
        len=split(unique[i],temp); \
        for (j=1;j<=len;j++) print temp[j],i > "File"i".txt"} }' \
file
```

The idea is to create a *hash-map*, with `unique[$2]=(unique[$2] FS $1)`, which literally means, treat `$2` as the index for the array `unique` and have values appended from `$1`, so at the end of each line processing of your input file, the array looks like this,

```
# <key>  <value(s)>
Chemist  Frank Harold George
Physicist  Charles
Programmer  Peter John Alex
```

The `END` clause is executed after all the lines are processed, so from the array constructed, using the `split()` function which splits on a single whistespace, we store the contents of the array value to the array `temp`, and `len` contains the number of elements resulting after the split.

A loop for each hash index and with each of the split element, the values are printed and stored in the file.

Comment: Thanks Inian. Quick question: Your _Awk_ script assumes that the file to be searched only contains one name per line correct ? I just used this as an example but in reality I have a 7 column wide file to "sort" by _grep_ or _awk_. If I create a hash-map I would have to create a hash of arrays with every key assigned to a line which would be represented by an array correct ? Example for the file: `27 Hatfield Peter London 4 8 Programmer` - Tab is the delimiter.

Comment: Provide your actual input to the question.